# spring mvc rest validation on all method parameters

Tags: spring-mvc

I would like to find a a way to validate a rest method based on all parameters outside the Controller.

**First Question:** Is there already a way to do it?

**Second Question:** If not - how can I hook the validation into spring mvc binding prozess.

A way how it could look like. It would be nice to mark the method with a new **@MethodValidation** Annotation:

```
@Validate
@MethodValidation(MyValidator.class)
public Response doSomthing(String param1, Integer param2, Something param3){}
```

Annotation

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface MethodValidation{
     Class<? extends MethodValidator<?, ?>>[] value();
}
```

Implement a Validator

```
public class MyValidator implements MethodValidator{
   public void validate(Object[] params, Errors errors){
      String param1 = (String ) params[0];
      Integer param2 = (Integer) params[1];
      Something param3 = (Something)params[3];
      // .... do some validations
      if(error)
           errors.reject("Some.error.done");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what kind of parameters exactly? a lot of spring stuff is actually available in ThreadLocals, if you dare to dig into it.

you CAN inject stuff into the binding process:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class FooControllerAdvice {
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(
            Date.class, 
            new CustomFooEditor()
        );
    }
}
```

and the actual editor:

```
public class CustomFooEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
}
```

but this doesn't give you that much of an edge over regular validation.

or you can use spring aop triggered by an annotation, then annotate your methods, with the config:

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
```

an aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ValidationAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(public * * (..))")  
    private void anyPublicMethod() {}

    @Around("anyPublicMethod() && @annotation(foo)")
    public Object all(
        ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, 
        Foo ann) throws Throwable {

    }
    [...]
}
```

an annotation:

```
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Foo {
}

public String value();
```

and then annotating your method:

```
@RequestMapping...
@Foo(value="foo.bar.ValidatorClassname")
public Response x() {
}
```

... so you see, there's a lot of ways you can go. i'd really like to know what keeps you from using standard validation?

.rm

Answer (score 0):

thanx for the answer. 
I hope I am right: The standard validation outside the controller just allows me to to validate each method parameter separately. 
I actually get into problems when the validation depends on 2 or more method parameter. This could be in following situation: Some thing is a part of an Object hierarchy:

```
public class Parent{
    private Integer id;
    private List<Something> childs;
    ...
}

public class Something{
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

The Constrain: it is not allowed that a Parent has 2 somethings in the list with the same name. For saving a new some thing I am calling the method.

```
@RequestMapping(
       value = "/chargingstation/{parentId}", 
        method = RequestMethod.Post)
public Response doSomthing(
                   @PathVariable("parentId") Integer parentId, 
                   Something param3)
```

Add the parentId to the Something-ModelOject was not an option.
So is there a way to handle this situation with the standard validation?